# Why does not ANTLR4 match "of" as a word and "," as punctuation?

Tags: regex, parsing, antlr, grammar, antlr4

I have a `Hello.g4` grammar file with a grammar definition:

```
definition : wordsWithPunctuation ;
words : (WORD)+ ;
wordsWithPunctuation : word ( word | punctuation word | word punctuation | '(' wordsWithPunctuation ')' | '"' wordsWithPunctuation '"' )*  ;
NUMBER : [0-9]+ ;
word : WORD ;
WORD : [A-Za-z-]+ ;
punctuation : PUNCTUATION ;
PUNCTUATION : (','|'!'|'?'|'\''|':'|'.') ;
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ; // skip spaces, tabs, newlines
```

Now, if I am trying to build a parse tree from the following input:

```
a b c d of at of abc bcd of
a b c d at abc, bcd
a b c d of at of abc, bcd of
```

it returns errors:

```
Hello::definition:1:31: extraneous input 'of' expecting {<EOF>, '(', '"', WORD, PUNCTUATION}
```

though the:

```
a b c d  at:  abc bcd!
```

works correct.

What is wrong with the grammar or input or interpreter?

If I modify the `wordsWithPunctuation` rule, by adding `(... | 'of' | ',' word | ...)` then it matches the input completely, but it looks suspicious for me - how the word `of` is different from the word `a` or `abc`? Or why the `,` is different from other `punctuation` characters (i.e., why does it match the `:` or `!`, but not `,`?)?

## Update1:

I am working with ANTLR4 plugin for Eclipse, so the project build happens with the following output:

```
ANTLR Tool v4.2.2 (/var/folders/.../antlr-4.2.2-complete.jar)
Hello.g4 -o /Users/.../eclipse_workspace/antlr_test_project/target/generated-sources/antlr4 -listener -no-visitor -encoding UTF-8
```

## Update2:

the presented above grammar is just a partial from:

```
grammar Hello;

text : (entry)+ ;

entry : blub 'abrr' '-' ('1')? '.' ('(' NUMBER ')')? sims '-' '(' definitionAndExamples ')' 'Hello' 'all' 'the' 'people' 'of' 'the' 'world';

blub : WORD ;

sims : sim (',' sim)* ;
sim : words ;

definitionAndExamples : definitions (';' examples)? ;

definitions : definition (';' definition )* ;
definition : wordsWithPunctuation ;

examples : example (';' example )* ;
example : '"' wordsWithPunctuation '"' ;

words : (WORD)+ ;
wordsWithPunctuation : word ( word | punctuation word | word punctuation | '(' wordsWithPunctuation ')' | '"' wordsWithPunctuation '"' )*  ;

NUMBER : [0-9]+ ;
word : WORD ;
WORD : [A-Za-z-]+ ;
punctuation : PUNCTUATION ;
PUNCTUATION : (','|'!'|'?'|'\''|':'|'.') ;
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ; // skip spaces, tabs, newlines
```

It looks now for me, that the words from the `entry` rule somehow breaking the other rules within the `entry` rule. But why? Is it a kind an anti-pattern in the grammar?

Comment: I am working in antlr4ide in eclipse and it has automatic build, so I assume that the regeneration happens in the background. Anyway I cleaned up the project, and after testing an example it immediately returns errors as I mentioned in the question. I have ANTLR 4.2.2, not 4.3

Comment: it seems that you are right, but I cannot understand why the rule from the top (i.e. "entry") conflicts with the rule from the lower levels, if it is already on the lower level?

Answer (score 3):

By including `'of'` in a parser rule, ANTLR is creating an implicit anonymous token to represent that input. The word `of` will always have that special token type, so it will never have the type `WORD`. The only place it may appear in your parse tree is at a location where `'of'` appears in a parser rule.

You can prevent ANTLR from creating these anonymous token types by separating your grammar into a separate `lexer grammar HelloLexer` in **HelloLexer.g4** and `parser grammar HelloParser` in **HelloParser.g4**. I highly recommend you *always* use this form for the following reasons:

1. Lexer modes only work if you do this.
2. Implicitly-defined tokens are one of the most common sources of bugs in a grammar, and separating the grammar prevents it from ever happening.

Once you have the grammar separated, you can update your `word` parser rule to allow the special token `of` to be treated as a word.

```
word
  : WORD
  | 'of'
  | ... other keywords which are also "words"
  ;
```