# Simple ANTLR grammar behaves different than expected

Tags: antlr, grammar

I've got the following simple ANTLR grammar:

```
grammar SysoutCommands;
commandline   : command;
command       : 'KEY action=interpret' ID '=' ID
              | 'KEY action=debug' 'file' '=' ID;
ID            : LOWER+;
fragment LOWER: 'a'..'z';
```

Feeding the grammar with the followig input

```
KEY action=interpret file=test
```

leads to a MismatchedTokenException(9!=4). Why is this the case? Any suggestions how to change the grammar in order to make the statement valid? Thanks in advance, Mario.

Comment: The problem is that `'file'` is not tokenized as an `ID`. Exactly the same issue as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24630419/why-does-not-antlr4-match-of-as-a-word-and-as-punctuation

Comment: Bart - thank you very much for this hint!